# Problem creating function for .net assembly in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-assembly

```
[SqlProcedure()]
public static void GetCustInfo(SqlString PhoneNo, out SqlString CustInfo)
{
    // code...
}
```

This is how I try to create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCustInfo] (@PhoneNo nvarchar(50))
RETURNS nvarchar(max) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS EXTERNAL NAME  CustFromPhone.[ManagedCodeAndSQLServer.BaseFunctionClass].GetCustInfo
```

and this is the error:

> CREATE FUNCTION failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value
>   do not match.

Comment: your right... look the comment below what my mistake was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even if you ask nicely ... a void function won't return something that can be converted to a nvarchar

Comment: I've read that sql procedure's can't have a return value. (maybe that's only true for vb.net?)

Comment: you are mixing up some concepts. to keep things simple: functions return something ... procedures don't. that's when you talk about the theoretic concept of functions or procedures. when it comes to everyday language, many people (including me) tend to call everything a function, or use both terms interchangable. to be precisely, there is no such thing as a void function ... if you have a `void foo()` that's always a procedure, but usually you don't have to worry about it. in this case it's simple ... your SQL function says it returns a nvarchar(max) ... your GetCustInfo(...) returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
[SqlProcedure()]
public static SqlString GetCustInfo(SqlString PhoneNo)
{
    // code...
}
```